# rotating package: positioning does not match documentation

Tags: rotating

I want a `sidewaystable` to appear with its top against the inner margin of the  body text. According to the `rotating` package documentation, these following settings:

```
\rotFPtop=0pt and  
\rotFPbot=0pt plus 1fil
```

will place a `sidewaystable` with its top nearest the edge of the page. However, what actually happens is that the *center* of the table is positioned at the margin, as is illustrated with the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=50mm,showframe]{geometry}

\rotFPtop=0pt
\rotFPbot=0pt plus 1fil
\fboxsep0pt
\def\tab{
   \begin{sidewaystable}
      \begin{center}
         \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
            line 1\\line 2\\line 3\\line 4\\\hline
            line 5\\line 6\\line 7\\line 8\\
         \end{tabular}}
      \end{center}
   \end{sidewaystable}
}
\begin{document}
\tab\newpage\tab
\end{document}
```

which shows that the top is neither at the edge of the page, nor at the margin (i.e. 50mm from the edge of the page in this example). **How can I get it at the margin?**

*(Edit by Gonzalo Medina)*
This image showing the problem mentioned was obtained from the code posted (I added `showframe` for visualization purposes) using TeX Live2012:

[image]

Comment: @Mico I added `showframe` to the code and uploaded an image of the resulting document showing the problem mentioned. Do you get a different result?

Comment: @WyboDekker I took the liberty of addind the package option `showframe` to `geometry` and uploading an image of the resulting document; I hope it's OK.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought about that myself. This makes very clear that it is not the top, but the center of the table that is aligned. Still don't know how to align the top...

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I understand the problem with the package, but found that if `\rotFPtop` is set to a value of `.5\dp\tmpbox+.5\ht\tmpbox+.19\baselineskip` (where the content has been set in `\tmpbox`), the top of the content aligns with the margin (left on odd pages, right on even pages).  I have verified this for boxes of various heights and depths, and using 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt documents.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=50mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\fboxsep0pt
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\def\prepbox#1{%
  \savebox{\tmpbox}{#1}%
  \setlength{\rotFPtop}{.5\dp\tmpbox+.5\ht\tmpbox+.19\baselineskip}%
}
\def\swtab{
   \begin{sidewaystable}
      \begin{center}
        \usebox{\tmpbox}
      \end{center}
   \end{sidewaystable}
}
\begin{document}
\prepbox{%
         \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c}
            line 1\\line 2\\line 3\\line 4\\\hline
            line 5\\line 6\\line 7\\line 8\\
         \end{tabular}}%
}
\swtab\newpage\swtab\newpage
\prepbox{\fbox{A baseline}}
\swtab\newpage\swtab\newpage
\prepbox{\fbox{baseline \stackon{\stackunder{a}{b}}{c}}}
\swtab\newpage\swtab\newpage
\prepbox{\fbox{A baseline \stackunder{\stackunder{a}{b}}{c}}}
\swtab\newpage\swtab\newpage
\prepbox{\fbox{baseline \Shortstack{A B C D E}}}
\swtab\newpage\swtab\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]